# android app is not working in samsung device

Tags: android, xml, samsung-mobile

when i'm trying to run my android app on Samsung device its always showing an error like:

> app has been unfortunately stopped

and also showing xml inflating error and drawable resources not found even i renamed existing apk and installed again either installed support library in android studio but error remain same.
but in redmi 3s device its working fine. what should i do please suggest something.
this is my error in console:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020157
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1884)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:425)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:132)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:211)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:186)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:197)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:479)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1151)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:95)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:234)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:290)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1042)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1065)
                  at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:460)
                  at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 965K, 13% free 14229K/16199K, paused 21ms+32ms, total 123ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 993K, 12% free 14774K/16775K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 37ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1591K, 15% free 14909K/17479K, paused 12ms+14ms, total 145ms
Application terminated.

draweritemmenu.xml this is my menu file.

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:icon="@drawable/login"
        android:title="Sign In" />
    <item android:title="Categories">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/fruit"
                    android:icon="@drawable/fruit"
                    android:title="Fruits" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/food"
                    android:icon="@drawable/thali"
                    android:title="Food" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
<item android:title="Best Deals">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/fruitoffer"
                android:icon="@drawable/fruitoffer"
                android:title="Offer On Fruits" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/foodoffer"
                android:icon="@drawable/offer"
                android:title="Offer On Food" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/aboutus"
         android:icon="@drawable/aboutus"
            android:title="About us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/contactus"
            android:icon="@drawable/contactus"
            android:title="Contact us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/faq"
            android:icon="@drawable/faq"
            android:title="FAQ" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

//this is my action menu xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search1"
    android:title="Filter By Food Name" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_search2"
    android:title="Filter By Fruit Name"
    android:icon="@drawable/foodbyname" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_search3"
    android:title="Filter By Food Price" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_search4"
    android:title="Filter By Fruit Price" />
```

Comment: It looks like it's failing while trying to inflate a menu XML.

Comment: Post your `res/menu/menu.xml` xml file.

Comment: okay i'am posting my menu xml.

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException:` show xml

Comment: Not the drawer xml. The **menu** xml.

Comment: i posted my menu xml

Comment: Is your drawable size is ok? I mean your image resolution

Comment: no i think its not okey. which size should use for navigation drawer images.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that one (or more) of your drawable (android:icon="@drawable/xxx") not found.
In my case, I put the picture into drawable-v21(folder) mistakenly (my devices' API=19). When I move it into drawable(folder), it's ok.